# Matplotlib axes labels squeeze tgt after I plot data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Before I plot data, it is like this:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax2=fig.add_axes([0.2,0.5,.2,.2])
ax1.tick_params(direction='in',top=True,right=True)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in',top=True,right=True)

ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2));


ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('y')
```

[image]

After I enter below codes:

```
x = np.arange(0,100)
y = x*2

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)
```

It became like this:

[image]

I have tried

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried to put tick format after plotting data. It doesn't work neither.

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax2=fig.add_axes([0.2,0.5,.2,.2])

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)

ax1.tick_params(direction='in',top=True,right=True)
ax2.tick_params(direction='in',top=True,right=True)

ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2))
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.2));

fig
```

Comment: Try putting the set ticks command after plotting

Comment: I tried it also. It doesn't work neither.

Comment: You create 6 ticks between 0 and 1. However you plot data in the range between 0 and 100 (or 200). So all your ticks are in the first percent of the axes, as expected.